# Why didn't Mark Watney use 19 cards instead of 17?

Tags: the-martian

We know that Mark set up a system where NASA could send ASCII via hex notation by setting up a system with 17 cards (16 hex digits plus ?) so that each covered a reasonable arc/sector so the message could be interpreted by him looking at where the camera was pointing.

I know he didn't use sixbit (which would have required only 9 cards - 8 octal digits + ?) because he wasn't a computer geek like Johansen.

But why didn't he use *19* cards with duplicates of each 4 and 5 placed 180° from each other?  It would have reduced arc width (and therefore accuracy) only slightly while reducing the all important (to him) message transmission time by reducing average camera pan time.  (Look at the ASCII table to see why 4 and 5 are important nibbles.)

(A mechanical engineer should have been able to figure this out, given the ASCII table.)

(By the way, I haven't seen this mentioned before, but the ? card was not just a end-of-message delimiter.  It was also a stuffer used between two consecutive identical nibbles, so that he didn't need to use camera dwell time to distinguish X from XX (or XXX...).  It seems obvious.)

Comment: This is off-topic for (1) asking for a real-world answer and (2) being primarily opinion based, so varying degree.   The short answer is just that he didn't.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - ok, where should I ask questions about how a hard scifi book/movie could have been better if certain things in it (plot holes, but not necessarily that "serious") had been changed?

Comment: Hi davidbak, thanks for asking.   This Q&A site is focused on evidence -based answers in- or out-of-universe.  For hypotheticals that probably can't be supported by evidence or reasonable speculation, you probably want to find a discussion board of some kind.   Maybe on reddit say.   Of course, if someone has an explanation in the book or in commentary by the author, then this question would be answerable, and I would happily reverse my close vote.

Comment: `why didn't he use` - because he used the method he used.  Maybe other methods didn't occur to him.  There are probably many ways that particular problem could have been solved. He chose the one he thought of.  It just needed to work, it didn't need to be the absolute best most optimized solution.

Comment: I don't recall that the book mentions how quickly the camera can turn; if it's fairly quick, the time saved by the extra cards would be negligible.

Answer (score 9):

This is addressed in the book:

> "We’ll need to talk faster than yes/no questions every half-hour. The camera can rotate 360 degrees, and I have plenty of antenna parts. Time to make an alphabet. But I can’t just use the letters A through Z. With my Question Card, that would be 27 cards around the lander. Each one would only get 13 degrees of arc. Even if JPL points the camera perfectly, there’s a good chance I won’t know which letter they meant
>
> I’ll have to use ASCII. That’s how computers manage characters. Each character has a numerical code between 0 and 255. Values between 0 and 255 can be expressed as 2 hexadecimal digits. By giving me pairs of hex digits, they can send any character they like, including numbers, punctuation, etc.
>
> **How do I know which values go with which characters? Because Johanssen’s laptop is a wealth of information. I knew she’d have an ASCII table in there somewhere. All computer geeks do.**
>
> So I’ll make cards for 0 through 9, and A through F. That makes 16 cards to place around the camera, plus the Question Card. 17 cards means over 21 degrees each. Much easier to deal with.
>
> Time to get to work!
>
> Spell with ASCII. Numbers 0-F at 21 degree increments. Will watch camera starting 11:00 my time. When message done, return to this position. Wait 20 minutes after completion to take picture (So I can write and post reply). Repeat process at top of every hour."

This was from the book, Sol 97. Emphasis is mine.

As you can see, the answer is fairly straightforward: an ASCII table was available on Johansen's laptop. To use any other notation would require having a table to decode. Was one present? No way of knowing. The book specifically says he found an ASCII table.

Which really isn't all that unreasonable, it can be handy to have. With the hexadecimal layout, all of the symbols could be spread around a reasonable arc intuitively without having to worry about 4's and 5's. And remember that at that point, he wasn't worried so much about time, aside from being bored, as he was in just being able to communicate with earth again. It would have taken him longer to work out a code with earth for which he didn't have a table- this was far easier.

In addition, note at the end- there was still a large amount of time left over. The speed boost wouldn't have been that huge, and he would have still been left with lots of dead time, but now he would have had more difficulty in deciphering the message. This also allowed him plenty of time to go in and out of the habitat in order to think and write replies.

Also, note that he says "Even if JPL points the camera perfectly" which, given that they're controlling a camera with a huge delay over the course of hundreds of thousands of km, is a real concern, so the decrease in accuracy is a real issue.

Edit: I think your question really boils down to: why didn't he make the code more time efficient? The answer is- his solution already was time efficient. They were passing one message per hour with time for him to take breaks as well. While you are more concerned with time, he was concerned with both time and accuracy. Your solution would have traded accuracy for time, or a commodity he needed for a commodity he had plenty of.

Once you start from that point, moving forward becomes less a "why did something happen like this in the movie" and more "my fan theory is better, so there!" Which isn't a question so much as looking for validation.

Comment: I assumed most of that is a quote from the book; feel free to correct

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you- I need to clean up the answer a little bit, but yes that entire quote was taken verbatim from the book.

Comment: The message would still be sent in ASCII, just like in the book.  Just that NASA would have a choice of two 4's and two 5's to use.  Which they would figure out easily enough with a panoramic view.  Then they could optimize the message being sent.  Mark would decode it as usual: write the nibble that he camera pointed at.  There would be no additional difficulty.

Comment: No arguing that there weren't other ways. Heck, it could have been done in binary or just using the alphabet. In this case, he was trying to conserve resources- but what he had at the time was time, especially given the time delay to earth. It was a tradeoff of time vs precision and resources. So *could* he have done otherwise? Yes. Why not? Maybe he just didn't think of it. This was a simple solution, so less likely to screw up.

Comment: The only thing that quote shows is he found ASCII table, probably confirmed it is indeed it, and openable. He could find the optimization you propose only if he actually looked at it with explicit intent at opitimization - and we have no proof of that

Comment: Microsoft Windows has a program called "charmap" that would show all of the ASCII codes. It's come with all versions of Windows I've ever used.

Comment: I don't believe it says in the book that he uses Windows. As for optomization- this was already an optomization he came up with on the fly. He was not the programmer of the group, he was a botanist mechanical engineer. He came up with a solution that worked consistently and within a time frame he could use.

Answer (score 2):

It was good enough. Your solution uses 2 *more* cards (which he was trying to conserve since, without an erasable pen, he couldn't reuse cards for his own transmission), did not increase the size of the available character set (which was already big enough), and *decreased* the angular space available for each card. In return, you gain only a negligible increase in speed. Remember, he was only scheduling one transmission from NASA per hour (at least in the book, haven't seen the movie), so as long as the message could be sent in less than an hour, that was fast enough. The problem of total transmission speed was only resolved once they were able to upgrade the rover software to enable two-way text communication.